# I am trying to make a matrix of buttons in React.js

Tags: reactjs, multiple-columns

I am trying to make a matrix of buttons left and what the buttons do on the right in react. When I go to render it won't render. I'm getting an anonymous function and I don't know what an anonymous function is. I tried using a column dependency from NPM. I don't know how to use this dependency is there an easier way to do this and clean up my code?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ButtonThemes, ButtonTypes, ButtonSizes } from "./buttonTypes";
import { IconTypes } from "./iconTypes";
import Button from "./Button";
import "./styles.css";


**var Columns = require('react-columns');

function Component(){
  var queries = [{
    columns: 2,
    query: 'min-width: 500px'
    }, {
    columns: 3,
    query: 'min-width: 1000px'
  }];

  function App() {
    return (
       <React.Fragment>
          <div className="App">
             <Columns queries={queries}>
               <Button
                 size={ButtonSizes.MEDIUM}
                 label="Button"
                 onClickHandler={() => alert("you clicked!")}
                 type={ButtonTypes.PRIMARY}
               />
               <p>
                 this is a button
               <p>
             </Columns>
          </div>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
   }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, <Columns />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReactDOM.render` call is invalid. [See docs on `render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render). Remove the `Columns` component.

Signature: `ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])`.

Your call should be: `ReactDOM.render(<App/>,rootElement)`.

Change imports to:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ButtonThemes, ButtonTypes, ButtonSizes } from "./buttonTypes";
import { IconTypes } from "./iconTypes";
import Button from "./Button";
import Columns from 'react-columns';
```

And your `render` to:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

It looks like you don't need both `Component` and `App`. Reduce it to this:

```
function App(){
  var queries = [{
    columns: 2,
    query: 'min-width: 500px'
    }, {
    columns: 3,
    query: 'min-width: 1000px'
  }];

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <Columns queries={queries}>
          <Button
            size={ButtonSizes.MEDIUM}
            label="Button"
            onClickHandler={() => alert("you clicked!")}
            type={ButtonTypes.PRIMARY}
          />
          <p>
            this is a button
          <p>
        </Columns>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

To answer your other question, an anonymous function is a function without a name. An example is your `onClickHandler` `onClickHandler={() => alert("you clicked!")`. You gave it a function inline, that is not stored anywhere, but redeclared on every render.

Regular function:

```
onClickHandler () => {
  alert('you clicked')
}

...
<Button
  size={ButtonSizes.MEDIUM}
  label="Button"
  onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
  type={ButtonTypes.PRIMARY}
/>
```

where as yours in anonymous:

```
<Button
  size={ButtonSizes.MEDIUM}
  label="Button"
  onClickHandler={() => alert("you clicked!")}
  type={ButtonTypes.PRIMARY}
/>
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using it the way you have it. Thats just what it means by "anonymous" function.

Comment: so would you render the file like ```ReactDOM.render(app, columns, rootElement container[, callback])``` I don't understand the documentation

Comment: but then how do I render the columns function?

Comment: No, you can only render one component into an element like that. `Columns` will be rendered because it is a sub-component of `App`.

Comment: It says that component is defined but never used. I'm using .https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-columns

Comment: It looks like it might be being imported wrong. Put it at the top as `import Columns from 'react-columns'`. But I don't know for sure as I'm not familiar with that library. It could be imported as `import { Columns }` instead. You'll have to check their docs.

Comment: I'm not using an on click function.

Comment: I looked at the repository for that library and it is a default export, so the first import example I gave should work.

Comment: I copied that on click directly from your question

Comment: it's still not letting me call the function within the overall app function. I'm so confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201041/discussion-between-brian-thompson-and-zachary-blumstein).

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean the code, You can create a static `JSON` which contains information about buttons, in your case id, label, Size & type.

After that, you can include that `JSON` in your `.js` or `.jsx` file render the json data in loop.

E.g.

**buttons_json.js**

```
import { ButtonThemes, ButtonTypes, ButtonSizes } from "./buttonTypes";

export const BUTTON_JSON = [
{
    'id': 1,
    'label': 'Button 1',
    'size': ButtonSizes.MEDIUM,
    'type': ButtonTypes.PRIMARY,
    'disabled': true
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'label': 'Button 2',
    'size': ButtonSizes.MEDIUM,
    'type': ButtonTypes.PRIMARY,
    'disabled': false
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'label': 'Button 3',
    'size': ButtonSizes.SMALL,
    'type': ButtonTypes.SECONDARY,
    'disabled': false
},
{
    'id': 4,
    'label': 'Button 4',
    'size': ButtonSizes.LARGE,
    'type': ButtonTypes.TERTIARY,
    'disabled': true
}];
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { IconTypes } from "./iconTypes";
import Button from "./Button";

import {BUTTON_JSON} from './buttons_json'; 


function render_buttons() {
return(
    <div className="App">
        {
            BUTTON_JSON.map((ins) => {
                return(
                    <Button
                        size={ins.size}
                        label={ins.label}
                        onClickHandler={() => alert("you clicked!")}
                        type={ins.type}
                        disabled={ins.disabled}
                    />
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
}

function App() {
return(
    <React.Fragment>
        {
            render_buttons()
        }
    </React.Fragment>
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: thanks @Rajeev G for this I tried this out. it says there is a syntax error stating ButtonThemes' is defined but never used

Comment: You can try removing `ButtonThemes ` as that is not needed that `JSON` part

Comment: is there a way I can bring React-bootstrap into your JSON file?

Comment: something is still wrong with your solution my file doesn't like  `import {BUTTON_JSON} from './buttons_json';`

Comment: Do you mean importing `react-bootstrap`?
If yes, then you can import `react-bootstrap` componets inside JSON file just like normal react component files.

Comment: You can check this example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-x9ktt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201045/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-rajeev-g).